# SSRS Reports that have been deployed - scroll rather than multiple pages

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

Once you have deployed a report and are viewing it through your browser is it possible to set up the report so that rather than clicking next page to view the rest of the data, all the results are put on one page where you can scroll from top to bottom without navigating through pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click outside area of the report > Report properties > Increase height to desired size.